# Vue: Event does not emit several values. Is there something wrong with v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3, v-model

I'm Vue beginner and have tried setting up a simple app that takes in some user input to display a result on an extra page / component.
Component A has 2 sliders. I'd like to pass both values to Component C. Currently only one value is passed.

I spent hours on this and have already received super valuable support on another question by @RoboKozo, but this keeps me from progressing any further.

Please find my [current code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-511qb5?file=src/App.vue) here.

Answer (score 0):

Bind both props, and emits

```
<component 
  :is="selectedComponent" 
  :modelValue="value" 
  :modelValue2="value2" 
  @update:modelValue="value = $event"
  @update2:modelValue2="value2 = $event"
>
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event name for updating the model value of `modelValue2` should be `update:modelValue2` (not `update2:modelValue2`):

```js
// ComponentC.vue
this.$emit('update:modelValue2', this.local2)
```

Then to bind `component.modelValue2` to `App.value2`, specify `modelValue2` as the `v-model` binding argument:

```html
<component v-model="value" v-model:modelValue2="value2">
```

Note you don't need to specify the binding argument for `modelValue` because that's the default.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-czy5jq?file=src%2FApp.vue)